# executing bash script on rotation with iio-sensor-proxy

Tags: gnome, bash-scripting, systemd, linux-kernel, events

I have a Tablet-laptop where i want to disable a gnome extension when the screen is rotated.

Auto-rotation works via iio-sensor-proxy.

it would be stupid to poll monitor-sensor constantly for resource reasons, right? is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You have already identified the moment when it must perform your action. Try to see (search for) what runs when screen rotation is detected and add your own script execution to the ones already executed. Note that you may also want to restore the use of disabled extensions when the reverse rotation occurs. Also you might want to add a grace time to not keep calling the script until it's finished or until the final rotation is decided (cases where you swing at the boundary between the two orientations)... Good Luck.